# Save results of each iteration in nested for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a point cloud made up of 37817 3D vertices ([data here](https://github.com/Patricklv/Concatenating-vectors-of-different-length-in-for-loop-in-MATLAB)). For each vertex `i`, I compute all neighbors within 15mm (`NeighborVert{i}`). A sphere is fit using these neighbors through `sphereFit` ([source code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34129-sphere-fit-least-squared)). Squared distance of each of the identified neighbor to the surface of the sphere, denoted as `epsilon{i}(j)`, is calculated to quantify residual of each neighbor to the fitted sphere. I then sum all values within `epsilon{i}` across `j` and store the result as `E(i)`, which measures the overall fit of the sphere for neighbors of vertex `i`. The above process is implemented through the MATLAB code below:

```
T = readtable("<path>\Vertices.xlsx", 'ReadVariableNames',false);
Vertices = table2array(T);
Vertfmt = pointCloud(Vertices);
radius = 15; 

for i = 1:size(Vertices, 1)
    [NeighborIndex{i}] = findNeighborsInRadius(Vertfmt, Vertices(i,:), radius);
    NeighborVert{i} = Vertices(NeighborIndex{i},:);
    [center(i, :), r(i)] = sphereFit(NeighborVert{i});
        for j = 1:length(NeighborIndex{i})
            epsilon{i}(j) = abs((NeighborVert{i}(j, 1) - center(i, 1))^2 + (NeighborVert{i}(j, 2) - center(i, 2))^2 + (NeighborVert{i}(j, 3) - center(i, 3))^2 - r(i)^2);
            E(i) = sum(epsilon{i}(j));
        end
end
```

`epsilon{i}` should contain multiple values because the squared distance of all neighbors of vertex `i` to the surface of the fitted sphere is stored. However, my result showed that each `epsilon{i}` contains only 1 value. How can I save all `epsilon{i}(j)`s within `epsilon{i}` during each iteration?

Besides, is my code for `E(i)` correctly sum across `j` for all `epsilon{i}(j)`s?

Comment: you could just go for `epsilon{i,j}`? then the results would be stored in a cell array, and you'd have to adapt further analysis accordingly. Keep in mind `i` is not a commonly used iterator variable in Matlab as it's the imaginary number

Comment: With `epsilon{i,j}`, I was returned a 37817*1 cell. However, it should have 37817 cells with each cell having the number of elements equal to the number of neighbors of the vertex under investigation. For example, vertext 1 has  618 neighbors so `epsilon{1}(j)` or `epsilon{1,j}` (I do not know how to correctly express) should have 618 elements, representing the residual of fit for each of the neighbors.

Comment: I haven't checked run the code yet but, double check you are indexing length(NeighborIndex(i)) correctly, it might need to be length(NeighborIndex{i})

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. However, the results did not change after this revision. Any further comments? I have corrected my code above accordingly.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why you're using a cell array. I think I'd have built a structure of length = size(Vertices,1) that could have a field that identifies the valid ID's from the original vertex cloud that are in-range and another field that gives the distance for each one of these points to the surface. Structures, like cells, are nice in that not every entry has to have the same number of elements. If you're interested in this approach I could work out a solution for you.

Comment: @Wick I first find number of vertices neighboring each vertex. Since this number varies from vertex to vertex, I have to use `length(NeighborIndex{i})` to denote the number of neighbors for each vertex.

Comment: @Patrick, I understand that. One could do the same thing with a structure.Each element of a structure can have variables of different size.